# Rolling by group in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I'm trying to roll my function through data.table by group and run into problems. Not sure should I change my function or is my call wrong. Here is simple example:

Data

```
 test <- data.table(return=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2),
                   sec=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"))
```

my function

```
zoo_fun <- function(dt, N) {
  (rollapply(dt$return + 1, N, FUN=prod, fill=NA, align='right') - 1)
}
```

Running it (I want to create new column momentum, which would be just product of latest 3 observations added by one for each security (so grouping by=sec).

```
test[, momentum3 := zoo_fun(test, 3), by=sec]

    Warning messages:
    1: In `[.data.table`(test, , `:=`(momentum3, zoo_fun(test, 3)), by = sec) :
      RHS 1 is length 10 (greater than the size (5) of group 1). The last 5 element(s) will be discarded.
    2: In `[.data.table`(test, , `:=`(momentum3, zoo_fun(test, 3)), by = sec) :
      RHS 1 is length 10 (greater than the size (5) of group 2). The last 5 element(s) will be discarded.
```

I get that warning and result is not expected:

```
> test
    return sec momentum3
 1:    0.1   A        NA
 2:    0.1   A        NA
 3:    0.1   A     0.331
 4:    0.1   A     0.331
 5:    0.1   A     0.331
 6:    0.2   B        NA
 7:    0.2   B        NA
 8:    0.2   B     0.331
 9:    0.2   B     0.331
10:    0.2   B     0.331
```

I was expecting B sec to be filled with 0.728 ((1.2*1.2*1.2) -1) with two NAs in start. What am I doing wrong? Is it that rolling functions won't work with grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `dt$return` the whole `data.table` is picked internally within the groups. Just use the column you need in the function definition and it will work fine:

```
#use the column instead of the data.table
zoo_fun <- function(column, N) {
  (rollapply(column + 1, N, FUN=prod, fill=NA, align='right') - 1)
}

#now it works fine
test[, momentum := zoo_fun(return, 3), by = sec]
```

As a separate note, you should probably not use `return` as a column or variable name.

Out:

```
> test
    return sec momentum
 1:    0.1   A       NA
 2:    0.1   A       NA
 3:    0.1   A    0.331
 4:    0.1   A    0.331
 5:    0.1   A    0.331
 6:    0.2   B       NA
 7:    0.2   B       NA
 8:    0.2   B    0.728
 9:    0.2   B    0.728
10:    0.2   B    0.728
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605112/3817004) suggested to use `reduce()` and `shift()` for rolling window problems with `data.table`. [This benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604943/3817004) showed that this might be considerably faster than `zoo::rollapply()`.

```
test[, momentum := Reduce(`*`, shift(return + 1.0, 0:2, type="lag")) - 1, by = sec][]
#    return sec momentum
# 1:    0.1   A       NA
# 2:    0.1   A       NA
# 3:    0.1   A    0.331
# 4:    0.1   A    0.331
# 5:    0.1   A    0.331
# 6:    0.2   B       NA
# 7:    0.2   B       NA
# 8:    0.2   B    0.728
# 9:    0.2   B    0.728
#10:    0.2   B    0.728
```

#### Benchmark (10 rows, OP data set)

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  zoo = test[, momentum := zoo_fun(return, 3), by = sec][],
  red  = test[, momentum := Reduce(`*`, shift(return + 1.0, 0:2, type="lag")) - 1, by = sec][],
  times = 100L
)
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
#  zoo 2318.209 2389.131 2445.1707 2421.541 2466.1930 3108.382   100   b
#  red  562.465  625.413  663.4893  646.880  673.4715 1094.771   100  a
```

#### Benchmark (100k rows)

To verify the benchmark results with the small data set, a larger data set is constructed:

```
n_rows <- 1e4
test0 <- data.table(return = rep(as.vector(outer(1:5/100, 1:2/10, "+")), n_rows),
                   sec = rep(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5L), n_rows))

test0
#        return sec
#     1:   0.11   A
#     2:   0.12   A
#     3:   0.13   A
#     4:   0.14   A
#     5:   0.15   A
#    ---           
# 99996:   0.21   B
# 99997:   0.22   B
# 99998:   0.23   B
# 99999:   0.24   B
#100000:   0.25   B
```

As `test` is being modified in place, each benchmark run is started with a fresh copy of `test0`.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  copy = test <- copy(test0),
  zoo  = {
    test <- copy(test0)
    test[, momentum := zoo_fun(return, 3), by = sec][]
  },
  red  = {
    test <- copy(test0)
    test[, momentum := Reduce(`*`, shift(return + 1.0, 0:2, type="lag")) - 1, by = sec][]
  },
  times = 10L
)

#Unit: microseconds
# expr         min          lq         mean      median          uq         max neval cld
# copy     282.619     294.512     325.3261     298.424     350.272     414.983    10  a 
#  zoo 1129601.974 1144346.463 1188484.0653 1162598.499 1194430.395 1337727.279    10   b
#  red    3354.554    3439.095    6135.8794    5002.008    7695.948   11443.595    10  a
```

For 100k rows, the `Reduce()` / `shift()` approach is more than 200 times faster than the `zoo::rollapply()`.

---

Apparently, there are different interpretations of what the expected result is.

To investigate this, a modified data set is used:

```
test <- data.table(return=c(0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25),
                   sec=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"))
test
#    return sec
# 1:   0.10   A
# 2:   0.11   A
# 3:   0.12   A
# 4:   0.13   A
# 5:   0.14   A
# 6:   0.21   B
# 7:   0.22   B
# 8:   0.23   B
# 9:   0.24   B
#10:   0.25   B
```

Note that the `return` values within in each group are varying which is different to the OP's data set where the `return`values for each `sec` group are constant.

With this, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44021386/3817004) (`rollapply()`) returns

```
test[, momentum := zoo_fun(return, 3), by = sec][]
#    return sec momentum
# 1:   0.10   A       NA
# 2:   0.11   A       NA
# 3:   0.12   A 0.367520
# 4:   0.13   A 0.404816
# 5:   0.14   A 0.442784
# 6:   0.21   B       NA
# 7:   0.22   B       NA
# 8:   0.23   B 0.815726
# 9:   0.24   B 0.860744
#10:   0.25   B 0.906500
```

[Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022808/3817004) returns:

```
test[test[ , tail(.I, 3), by = sec]$V1, res := prod(return + 1) - 1, by = sec][]
#    return sec      res
# 1:   0.10   A       NA
# 2:   0.11   A       NA
# 3:   0.12   A 0.442784
# 4:   0.13   A 0.442784
# 5:   0.14   A 0.442784
# 6:   0.21   B       NA
# 7:   0.22   B       NA
# 8:   0.23   B 0.906500
# 9:   0.24   B 0.906500
#10:   0.25   B 0.906500
```

The `Reduce()`/`shift()` solution returns:

```
test[, momentum := Reduce(`*`, shift(return + 1.0, 0:2, type="lag")) - 1, by = sec][]
#    return sec momentum
# 1:   0.10   A       NA
# 2:   0.11   A       NA
# 3:   0.12   A 0.367520
# 4:   0.13   A 0.404816
# 5:   0.14   A 0.442784
# 6:   0.21   B       NA
# 7:   0.22   B       NA
# 8:   0.23   B 0.815726
# 9:   0.24   B 0.860744
#10:   0.25   B 0.906500
```

Comment: How large is your test data? Benchmarks on very small data can be misleading when applied to (large) real world data

Comment: @docendodiscimus I've added a 100k rows benchmark which confirms the indication of the benchmark results gained with the small OP data set.

Comment: Thanks, I'm at state that running speed takes anyway minimal amount of my time (coding takes alot). How about if I want to use different functions in that reduce? sd, mean... do they work as well. I like rollapply because it is easy to change functions.