# rollsum producing unexpected NA

Tags: r, zoo

Using the `rollsum` function in `zoo`, I am seeing NAs in place of what I would expect to be valid values.  `rollapply` using `sum` works as expected, but `rollsum` does not:

```
library(zoo)
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,4,5,6)
x
```

> ```
> [1]  1  2  3 NA NA  4  5  6
> ```

```
rollapply(x, 3, FUN=sum, fill=NA)
```

> ```
> [1] NA  6 NA NA NA NA 15 NA
> ```

```
rollsum(x, 3, fill=NA)
```

> ```
> [1] NA  6 NA NA NA NA NA NA
> ```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in the optimization `rollsum` is using?

Comment: `?zoo::rollsum` states that `rollmean` does not handle `NA`s -- probably due to using `cumsum`. Seems to be the case for `rollsum` too.

Comment: Makes sense.  Odd that it produces an incorrect result instead of an error.

Comment: Maybe `RcppRoll::roll_sum` could be an alternative for you

Comment: @Floo0 several OOM faster than rollapply, thanks for the tip.  Benchmarking zoo:rollapply vs RcppRoll::roll_sum for those interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21371399/736755

Comment: `rollsum` is an optimized version of `rollapply(..., sum)` to  provide speed while still being written in 100% R but in exchange it does not handle NAs.  The help file says that `rollmean` does not handle `NA` values but it should have said that `rollmean` and `rollsum` do not.  If you want to give it NA values use `rollapply`.

Comment: Achim just mentioned to me that he has fixed the help file in the development version of zoo to now refer to `rollsum` and not just `rollmean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default methods of rollmean and rollsum do not handle inputs that contain NAs. In such cases, use rollapply instead.

Answer (score 0):

`rollsum` is defined within `rollmean.R` as follows:

```
rollsum <- function(x, k, fill = if (na.pad) NA, na.pad = FALSE, 
    align = c("center", "left", "right"), ...) {
    UseMethod("rollsum")
}
```

where the method is:

```
rollsum.zoo <- function(x, k, fill = if (na.pad) NA, na.pad = FALSE, 
    align = c("center", "left", "right"), ...) {

  if (!missing(na.pad)) warning("na.pad is deprecated. Use fill.")

  align <- match.arg(align)

  if (length(dim(x)) == 2) {
      # merge is the only zoo specific part of this method

      out <- do.call("merge", c(lapply(1:NCOL(x), function(i) {
        rollsum(x[, i, drop = TRUE], k, fill = fill, align = align, ...)
      }), all = FALSE))
      if (ncol(x) == 1) dim(out) <- c(length(out), 1)
      colnames(out) <- colnames(x)
      return(out)
  }

  n <- length(x)
  stopifnot(k <= n)

  ix <- switch(align,
      "left" = { 1:(n-k+1) },
      "center" = { floor((1+k)/2):ceiling(n-k/2) },
      "right" = { k:n })

  xu <- unclass(x)
  y <- xu[k:n] - xu[c(1, seq_len(n-k))] # difference from previous
  y[1] <- sum(xu[1:k])       # find the first
  # sum precomputed differences
  rval <- cumsum(y)

  x[ix] <- rval
  na.fill(x, fill = fill, ix)

}
```

If you step through the function you'll see it's actually not because of `cumsum` that the result evaluates to NA where you'd expect 15 (or at least that's not the first cause of it -- if you were to fix the current problem maybe `cumsum` would also cause a problem, I don't know). It's the line

`y <- xu[k:n] - xu[c(1, seq_len(n-k))]`.

`rollsum` is a new function in the `zoo` package and doesn't yet handle NA's well, so I'd suggest staying with `rollapply`.