# How can I calculate wind direction average in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set which consist of wind direction vector, as follows:

```
wdir <- c(296.9, 215.2, 204.8, 110.8, 287.6, 203.4, 253.1, 46.0, 298.8,  62.8, 183.4, 62.3,
          44.3, 97.6, 78.6, 125.6, 116.9, 121.0, 111.2, 335.8, 287.4, 51.7, 232.6, 265.5,
          269.7, 20.5, 17.0, 310.8)
```

Scalar values are in degrees.

How can I calculate mean wind direction?

Comment: How about `mean(wdir)`?

Comment: [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491738/how-do-you-calculate-the-average-of-a-set-of-angles)

Comment: @thothal that won't give the desired answer since the data is degrees

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done using the `circular` package.

To get the mean of `45` and `315` you can use:

```
library(circular)
mean(circular(c(pi/4,7*pi/4)))
#Circular Data: 
#Type = angles 
#Units = radians 
#Template = none 
#Modulo = asis 
#Zero = 0 
#Rotation = counter 
#[1] -1.570092e-16
```

The reason it isn't exactly `0` is because of [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847918/floating-point-precision-in-r)  in `R`.

To get the mean of `wdir`you can use:

```
mean(circular(wdir, units = "degrees"))
#Circular Data: 
#Type = angles 
#Units = degrees 
#Template = none 
#Modulo = asis 
#Zero = 0 
#Rotation = counter 
#[1] 41.05411
```

Another example:

```
mean(circular(c(7*pi/2,pi/4, pi/2, 7*pi/2 )))
#Circular Data: 
#Type = angles 
#Units = radians 
#Template = none 
#Modulo = asis 
#Zero = 0 
#Rotation = counter 
#[1] -0.3926991
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have a additional question. That's a hourly data and I want to calculate daily, 6hour seq etc... various time interval mean. How can I do this?

Comment: @LeeKi-Seop [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745402/r-rolling-window-function-with-adjustable-window-and-step-size-for-irregularly) might help or you may get help with that problem by asking another question with reproducible data.

Comment: This is a great solution, but note that `mean(circular(data))` will calculate the answer as rotation around the circle from zero, in positive up to 180 and negative down to -180.  You'll want to add 360 to *just* the negative values to get answers from 0 to 360.

Answer (score 4):

You can't simply average the wind direction, you need the speed for each direction and with the speed you can evaluate the average considering the vector form. Another way is to convert wind speed and direction into u and v components, than you can average u and v separately and then evaluating speed and direction. Wind spd = sqrt(u^2+v^2); wind dir = atan2(u,v)*(180/pi)+180

Comment: How would you go about this if you only have wind speed and wind direction, but don't know the u and v components?